# hover Works in demo but not in practice

Tags: javascript, html

http://jsfiddle.net/384k9hng/1/

SO i have this demo that works great! But I put it in my website and it doesn't work!!!!

```js
$('#test').hover(function() {
    if ($('#hello:hover').length > 0) {
         document.getElementById('hello').textContent = "A god like being, power swirls and mystifies beholder. Thousands of creations wander around the blank room. The room that seems to never end, that cannot be perceived by those other than the creator. The box confining those within, puppeteered by the being. The hands block those within from escaping, the hands of the creator";
    } else {
     document.getElementById('hello').textContent = "It pulls on it's chains";
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
  
    
  </head>

  
  <style>
 div{

        background: orange;
    }  
</style>
  
  <body>
   
 
<div id= "chainbox" >
  
  <h2> <I id = "chain" > "It pulls on it's chains" </I>   </h2> 
  
  </div>
```

This is what i put into my website and it wont work. How do I fix it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have jQuery linked in the project before running a jQuery script in your project. That error means it isn't reading the `$` symbol. Put this script tag above your jQuery script.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`